# How to interrupt the loading of a webpage?

Tags: java, jsp, web

I know the title is a bit confusing. I will describe my task:

Now I'm writing a webpage, which allow me to download some data or do some other stuff. The front end is jsp and the back end is java. So every time when I do something on this page(e.g. sort the data or download the data), a request will be sent to java and after data processing the .jsp page will be refreshed and loaded again(of cause after sorting it should be refreshed). But I just found that if I download a data with the following code, the refreshing will be interrupted:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); // response is HttpServletResponse
doSomeOutput(out); // Just write something into OutputStream

out.flush(); // **PAY ATTENTION**. The refreshing is interrupted here!
out.close();
```

When I was debugging, the page was keeping loading until the third line. And then the page was not refreshed and the data was download.

I hope you can understand what I'm talking about:(

So now I have 2 questions: 1. How can I let the process keep working after out.flush();? 2. In my task I need the same behavior(the process is interrupted) in some other modules, but there's nothing to be download. So how can I interrupt the process besides out.flush();?

Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29
"Calling flush() on the ServletOutputStream commits the response"

as i understand this: active refreshing is stopped, as we got main part of data. But you would be able to send data even after commit. So you can keep working after flush.
Set headers are also sent with flush.

2) Pls explain more thoroughly. call "return", or close?

Comment: Hi Vovka! Thanks for your answer! We don't have a "return", the remaining code is also executed. So I guess "Calling flush() on the ServletOutputStream commits the response" is the right answer. Since the response is already committed, the remaining code has no influence on the page, right? So for the second question. what I want is just have the same behavior, commit the response and stop refreshing and stop influence on the page. But my question is what is the easiest way to commit the response without downloading anything? Thank you!

Comment: Do you work inside servlet "doGet" or "doPost" method? Processing finished when your method is finished. So you have to call "return". http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: To be honest, I'm only allowed to edit the code inside a "process()" method, which is dealing with different request. And in normal situation, after dealing with all the requests, the whole page will be refreshed. But I found that "downloading" didn't refresh the page, even error exist in log: Error calling continueProcess: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed. I don't care about this error, but just want the same behavior: commit the response, stop refreshing, without downloading anything.

Comment: I tried creating the OutputStream, and flushed it without writing anything in it, the refreshing of the page was stopped at out.close() but the whole page turn blank.....Thank you!